# Splitting contents of a dictionary based on size

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, chunking

**Problem definition**

I have a dictionary of the form `<string, Tuple<List<T>, int>>`. Item2 of the tuple is size in bytes of the Item1 (List).

I would like to chunk it up into multiple dictionaries each of the form `<string, List<T>>`, based on a pre-defined max size for each dictionary.

So, it is possible that I may have to break up a values list (`List<T>`; Item1 of the tuple) (corresponding to a single K-V pair) to go into multiple dictionaries.

**What I have tried so far**

I have come up with the code below which does the chunking in a very primitive fashion - this is still WIP and does not fully work yet. The logic here is to walk through each K-V pair and get all items from a list until we hit that pre-defined aforementioned max size.

But before I go any further with this code, I feel there has got to be a better way of doing this. Any pointers are appreciated.

```
private async Task ChunkAsPerPayloadSizeAsync(IDictionary<string, Tuple<List<T>, int>> bufferSnapshot)
{
    var dict = GetDictionary(bufferSnapshot); // This return the bufferSnapshot dictionary in the form <string, List<T>>
    if (GetSizeOfDictionaryInBytes(dict) <= PayloadSizeInBytes)
    {
        await _makeRequest(dict); // This is a callback with the chunk in the correct size
    }
    else
    {
        var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
        var sizeInBytes = 0;
        while (bufferSnapshot.Count > 0)
        {
            var itemId = bufferSnapshot.FirstOrDefault().Key;
            if (bufferSnapshot.TryGetValue(itemId, out var data))
            {
                var thisSize = data.Item2 + FindSize<string>.SizeOf(itemId);
                if (sizeInBytes + thisSize <= PayloadSizeInBytes)
                {
                    sizeInBytes += thisSize;
                    dict2.Add(itemId, data.Item1);
                    bufferSnapshot.Remove(itemId);
                }
                else
                {
                    // now we have to chunk the values
                    var sizeInBytesOfValuesList = data.Item2;
                    var valuesCount = data.Item1.Count;
                    var sizePerValue = sizeInBytesOfValuesList / valuesCount;
                    var spaceAvailable = RequestPayloadSizeInBytes - sizeInBytes - FindSize<string>.SizeOf(itemId);
                    var numberOfValuesToTake = spaceAvailable / sizePerValue;
                    if (numberOfValuesToTake > 0)
                    {
                        if (numberOfValuesToTake < data.Item1.Count)
                        {
                            var items = data.Item1.Take(numberOfValuesToTake);
                            data.Item1.RemoveRange(0, numberOfValuesToTake);
                            dict2.Add(itemId, items.ToList());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dict2.Add(itemId, data.Item1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you already have the size, you can use `Where` to filter the dictionary by the tuple's reported size, then use `Except` to get the rest, then simply call `ToDictionary` on the results. I don't know exactly *what* you're doing in all that code, as I'm afraid to look directly at it, lest I fall down the rabbit hole.

Comment: It's not very clear to me. Do you want a list of what?

Every tuple has an element with a max size in it? You should provide more informations

Comment: Is this a [knapsack-type problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) where you're trying to cram as many items into each bucket as possible or is it okay to just iterate through the items until you get to one that would exceed maxSize and then start on the next bucket?

Comment: @itsme86, yes, it is a knapsack-type problem. More like 2 nested knapsack problems.

Comment: Why the downvote? I have a problem statement, code sample of my own efforts, and as clearly stated I am looking for pointers, not a spoon-fed solution. The pointer to the knapsack problem in the comment above has actually helped.

Answer (score 0):

Could you `bufferSnapshot.Select(b => b.Item2)` which would give you an array of lengths, then use Take/Skip to grab the elements you want into shorter sequences that you are after?

Comment: That would not work because I need the break down the values list as well (Item1 of the tuple).